# XSL - Display based on other XML - Conditional

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML structure as is below

```
<AccountDetails>
<AdditionalPvtDetails seq="1" id="110095115">
<PvtClientFullname>YYYY</PvtClientFullname>
<PvtGender>FEMALE</PvtGender>
<PvtIdentification>
<PvtVoterID>KXF1067981</PvtVoterID>
</PvtIdentification>
<PvtAddress>
<AdditionalAddressDetails seq="1">
<Addressline>ST2</Addressline>
<State>OH</State>
<PIN>56708</PIN>
</AdditionalAddressDetails>
</PvtAddress>
</AdditionalPvtDetails>
<AdditionalPvtDetails seq="2" id="110095163">
<PvtClientFullname>YYYY </PvtClientFullname>
<PvtGender>FEMALE</PvtGender>
<PvtIdentification/>
<PvtAddress>
<AdditionalAddressDetails seq="1">
<Addressline>ST2</Addressline>
<State>OH</State>
<PIN>56708</PIN>
</AdditionalAddressDetails>
</PvtAddress>
</AdditionalPvtDetails>
<AdditionalPvtDetails seq="3" id="110095180">
<PvtClientFullname>YYYY</PvtClientFullname>
<PvtGender>FEMALE</PvtGender>
<PvtIdentification/>
<PvtAddress>
<AdditionalAddressDetails seq="1">
<Addressline>ST1</Addressline>
<State>OH</State>
<PIN>56708</PIN>
</AdditionalAddressDetails>
</PvtAddress>
</AdditionalPvtDetails>
<Account seq="1" id="110095115" ReportedDate="2011-07-11">
<AccountNumber> 8601N70201</AccountNumber>
<CurrentBalance>0</CurrentBalance>
<Institution>Pvt Limited</Institution>
<DisbursedAmount>12000</DisbursedAmount>
<LoanPurpose>510</LoanPurpose>
<SanctionAmount>12000</SanctionAmount>
<DateReported>2011-07-11</DateReported>
<DateOpened>2009-09-24</DateOpened>
<DateClosed>2010-09-09</DateClosed>
<LoanCycleID>01</LoanCycleID>
<DateSanctioned>2009-09-18</DateSanctioned>
<DateApplied>2009-09-17</DateApplied>
<AppliedAmount>12000</AppliedAmount>
<NoOfInstallments>50</NoOfInstallments>
<RepaymentTenure>Weekly</RepaymentTenure>
<InstallmentAmount>276</InstallmentAmount>
<KeyPerson>
<Name>XXX</Name>
<RelationType>Husband</RelationType>
</KeyPerson>
<Nominee>
<Name/>
<RelationType/>
</Nominee>
<AccountStatus>Closed Account</AccountStatus>
</Account>
<Account seq="2" id="110095163" ReportedDate="2011-07-11">
<AccountNumber> 8601N70202</AccountNumber>
<CurrentBalance>4400</CurrentBalance>
<Institution>Pvt Limited</Institution>
<DisbursedAmount>20000</DisbursedAmount>
<LoanPurpose>302</LoanPurpose>
<SanctionAmount>20000</SanctionAmount>
<DateReported>2011-07-11</DateReported>
<DateOpened>2010-09-30</DateOpened>
<LoanCycleID>02</LoanCycleID>
<DateSanctioned>2010-09-24</DateSanctioned>
<DateApplied>2010-09-23</DateApplied>
<AppliedAmount>20000</AppliedAmount>
<NoOfInstallments>50</NoOfInstallments>
<RepaymentTenure>Weekly</RepaymentTenure>
<InstallmentAmount>460</InstallmentAmount>
<KeyPerson>
<Name>XXX</Name>
<RelationType>Husband</RelationType>
</KeyPerson>
<Nominee>
<Name/>
<RelationType/>
</Nominee>
<AccountStatus>Current Account</AccountStatus>

</Account>
<Account seq="3" id="110095180" ReportedDate="2011-07-11">
<AccountNumber> 8601N7201</AccountNumber>
<CurrentBalance>0</CurrentBalance>
<Institution>Pvt Limited</Institution>
<DisbursedAmount>4000</DisbursedAmount>
<LoanPurpose>510</LoanPurpose>
<SanctionAmount>4000</SanctionAmount>
<DateReported>2011-07-11</DateReported>
<DateOpened>2010-03-04</DateOpened>
<DateClosed>2011-02-17</DateClosed>
<LoanCycleID>01</LoanCycleID>
<DateSanctioned>2010-02-19</DateSanctioned>
<DateApplied>2010-02-18</DateApplied>
<AppliedAmount>4000</AppliedAmount>
<NoOfInstallments>50</NoOfInstallments>
<RepaymentTenure>Weekly</RepaymentTenure>
<InstallmentAmount>92</InstallmentAmount>
<KeyPerson>
<Name>XXX</Name>
<RelationType>Husband</RelationType>
</KeyPerson>
<Nominee>
<Name/>
<RelationType/>
</Nominee>
<AccountStatus>Closed Account</AccountStatus>
</Account>
</AccountDetails>
```

I am looking for output like below

```
ID:110095115   Name :YYYY     Account number : 8601N70201   Status : Closed Account   No.Of Install:50
ID:110095163   Name :YYYY     Account number : 8601N70202   Status : Current Account   No.Of Install:50
```

I want to know how I can match the "AdditionalPvtDetails" items like Name,Geneder,Identification for each "account" information and format the output as shown above.. basically, "AdditinalPvtDetails" and "account" has to be joined by "Id"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could make use of **xsl:key** here to look up the **AdditionalPvtDetails** elements whilst positioned on **Account** elements

```
<xsl:key name="additional" match="AdditionalPvtDetails" use="@id" />
```

This created a key named **additional** which can be used to look-up **AdditionalPvtDetails** using their **id** attribute. For example, assuming you were positioned on an **Account** element, you could look up the gender of the account as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('additional', @id)/PvtGender" />
```

As a simple example, consider this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="additional" match="AdditionalPvtDetails" use="@id" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="AccountDetails/Account" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Account">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('AccountID: ', @id, ' ')" />
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Gender: ', key('additional', @id)/PvtGender, '&#13;')" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is returned:

```
AccountID: 110095115 Gender: FEMALE
AccountID: 110095163 Gender: FEMALE
AccountID: 110095180 Gender: FEMALE
```